# Hibernate Timestamp to LocalDateTime conversion unexpected result

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, java-8, hsqldb

I've an issue with the conversion of 1000-01-01 00:00:00.0 to a LocalDateTime object. i've already checked the [Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#MIN) to see if maybe 1000-01-01 isn't supported, but that doesn't seem the problem.

The versions I'm using
hibernate-core: 5.2.1.Final
hibernate-commons-annotations: 5.0.1.Final
hsqldb: 2.3.4
spring-test-dbunit: 1.2.0

This is how startDate looks in MyEntity.class

```
@Basic
@Column(name = "start_date", nullable = false)
public LocalDateTime getstartDate() {
    return startDate;
}
```

Hibernate creates it like this:

```
Query:[create table my_table (end_date timestamp not null, start_date timestamp not null)]
```

I've a (example) dataset with the following row

`<my_table startDate="1000-01-01 00:00:00.0" endDate="4000-01-01 00:00:00.0" />`

DBUnit is loading the data in an in memory database using Hibernate

```
Query:["insert into my_table(START_DATE, END_DATE) values (?, ?)"]
Params:[(1=1000-01-01 00:00:00.0,2=4000-01-01 00:00:00.0)]
```

In my JUnit test I fetch the data using an (Hibernate) Entitymanager and following named query:

```
@NamedQuery(
            name = "MyTable.fetchAll",
            query = "FROM MyTable m"
)
```

The select query (simplified):

```
Query:["select end_date as date_e12_4_, start_date as date_s13_4_ from my_table mytable0_"]
```

In my JUnit test I assert the returned result but I get an AssertionError:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected :MyEntity{startDate=1000-01-01T00:00, endDate=4000-01-01T00:00}
Actual   :MyEntity{startDate=1000-01-05T23:09:21, endDate=4000-01-01T00:00}
```

My startDate 1000-01-01T00:00 becomes 1000-01-**05T23:09:21**.
The problem doesn't occur with the endDate.

Has anyone had this issue before? Or does anyone know how to solve it?
Please let me know if you need some more information. 
Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Update**: it works when I use LocalDate instead of LocalDateTime.

Comment: What engine is the in-memory database using? Is it possible that the database doesn't support such dates?

Comment: It's only since I started using LocalDateTime that I've been experiencing this issue. I used java.sql.Timestamp before without a problem. The tests that are failing existed already during the Timestamp period of my project.

Answer (score 1):

For the new type from Java 8, you need another dependency from Hibernate.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-java8</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

After adding this, use LocalDateTime like normal Basic type.

```
private LocalDateTime validFrom;
```

**Updated**
I try to reproduce your situation.
Here is how i implemented the class.

```
@Entity
public class MyTable extends ABaseEntity {

private LocalDateTime startDate;

@Type(type="org.hibernate.type.LocalDateTimeType")
public LocalDateTime getStartDate() {
    return startDate;
}

public void setStartDate(LocalDateTime startDate) {
    this.startDate = startDate;
}

}
```

Data in database

```
ID  STARTDATE
1   25-AUG-16 12.00.00.000000000 AM
```

The result when i read back

```
2016-08-25T00:00
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: First of all thank you for your response. I've never mentioned that Hibernate wasn't able to parse a Timestamp to a LocalDateTime object. The problem was actually with the timezone I think.